# conflicted JQuery and Prototype on website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a legacy website using Prototype. But I want to use JQuery in addition. How can I use Prototype and JQuery an the same page when they both override the `$` sign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery". However, you can override that default by calling jQuery.noConflict() at any point after jQuery and the other library have both loaded. For example:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

see http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the `.noConflict()` way, you could also scope your jQuery code.

```
<script>
(function($) {
//write your jQuery code here.

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to be able to use some shorthand, do

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

now you can use j$ instead of $ for jquery

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Elementenfresser's answer, I'd suggest that on top of using jQuery.noConflict(); you could wrap the entire jQuery code with an anonymous function, keeping all your jQuery code intact without the need to change all "$"'s to "jQuery"'s.

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($){
    $("div").hide(); //will use jQuery
  })(jQuery);

 $("div").hide(); //will use prototype
 jQuery("div").hide(); //will use jQuery again.
```

You can wrap all your javascript files that are using jQuery with anonymous functions. You won't have to change the $ to jQuery at all. It's also a performance improvement, as all variables declared within the functions will not be attached to the global scope - making your application faster.